# Clark-Ocone Formula for computing SDE

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, malliavin-calculus

If we know $X_t$ is an $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued process solving the SDE
$$
dY_t = a(t,Y_t)dt +b(t,Y_t)dW_t,
$$
then does the Clark-Ocone Formula and the fundamental theorem of Malliavin Calculus imply that:
\begin{align}
X_T = & E[X_T] + \int_0^{T}E[D_tX_t|\mathfrak{F}_t]dW_t\\
\therefore & \int_0^{T} E[D_tX_t|\mathfrak{F}_t]dW_t  = X_T - E[X_T] \\
\therefore & E[D_tX_t|\mathfrak{F}_t] = DX_T - DE[X_T] \\
\therefore & E[D_tX_t|\mathfrak{F}_t] = DX_T - E[DX_T]
\end{align}
In particular if we set $Y_t = DX_t$ then can we conclude that
\begin{align}
E[Y_t|\mathfrak{F}_t] & = Y_T - DE[\int_0^TY_tdW_t]?
\end{align}

Comment: Not sure all your steps are valid... is $D\int XdW = X?$

Comment: Shouldn't $DE[X_T]$ be 0 ? Even in Malliavin's calculus the derivative of a constant should be null unless I missed something. Regards

Comment: Saying $Y_t = DX_t$ doesn't even make sense, does it?  For each fixed $t$, $Y_t$ is a random variable but $DX_t$ is a process.